# How to provide SqlDelight database in Compose Multiplatform using KodeIn

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight, kodein, compose-multiplatform

So far i've managed to declare expect class for DriverFactory

```
expect class DriverFactory {
    fun createDriver(): SqlDriver
}

actual class DriverFactory(private val context: Context) {
    actual fun createDriver(): SqlDriver {
        return AndroidSqliteDriver(AppDatabase.Schema, context, "test.db")
    }
}

actual class DriverFactory {
    actual fun createDriver(): SqlDriver {
        return NativeSqliteDriver(AppDatabase.Schema, "test.db")
    }
}
```

Then create the database

```
class LocalDatabase(databaseDriverFactory: DriverFactory) {
     val database = AppDatabase(
        driver = databaseDriverFactory.createDriver(),
        saved_team_tableAdapter = Saved_team_table.Adapter(
            playersAdapter = dbPlayerListAdapter,
            playerOffsetsAdapter = dbOffsetListAdapter
        )
    )
}
```

But now when i'd like to provide the database, I'm unable to provide the DriverFactory as it's an expect class.

Attempting to provide the specific Android or iOS factory's is also difficult as the Android one needs a context?

```
val dataModule = DI.Module(name = "dataModule") {
    // Need to provide DriverFactory
    bindSingleton { LocalDatabase(instance()) }
    bindProvider<SavedTeamRepository> { SavedTeamRepositoryImpl(instance()) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But now when i'd like to provide the database, I'm unable to provide the DriverFactory as it's an expect class.

The `instance()` you are trying to access in `bindSingleton { LocalDatabase(instance()) }` must be provided somewhere by the KodeIn.

1. For the purpose of understanding let's rename your driver factory for Android:

```kotlin
actual class AndroidDriverFactory(private val context: Context) {
    actual fun createDriver(): SqlDriver {
        return AndroidSqliteDriver(AppDatabase.Schema, context, "test.db")
    }
}
```

2. Now we have to provide this in Your **androidMain** package

```kotlin
bind<DriverFactory>() with singleton { AndroidDriverFactory(androidContext()) }
```

3. Now the `instance()` value mentioned in `bindSingleton { LocalDatabase(instance()) }` (**this must be under commonMain**) would have the provided value by the KodeIn.

> Attempting to provide the specific Android or iOS factory's is also difficult as the Android one needs a context?

Now you can provide DriverFactory for iOS as well under **iOSMain**. This time context is not needed.